# IDE won't let me type what I want

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ide, autocorrect

A couple weeks ago my IDE started getting very forceful...  Since it's hard to explain what I mean, here is a video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNGMlWwmzpg

It lets me do what I want outside of the parenthesis, so maybe it thinks it's bad syntax two put to evaluations inside, but even if that's true, I don't want my IDE *restricting* what I can type, it should just use intellisense and put the squigglies.

Here are the extensions I have installed (I disabled the one I installed most recently but it didn't help).  I've used almost all of these forever without problem...

[image]

**update**: Offered a bounty because this is making me rage.  I have disabled ALL extensions and right now I have the following line:

```
output += "<div title='" + dr("ServiceGroupType_Desc") + "'>" + dr("ServiceGroupType_Desc") + "</div>"""
```

I **cannot** delete the two extra quotes at the end.  It just won't let me.

Comment: Have you tried to run "devenv /SafeMode" http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms241278.aspx

Comment: Is this happening even after you close down Visual Studio and bring it up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as you and had to **uninstall** the `Codealike` plugin to get it working again.

Comment: However... I uninstalled the rest of my disabled extensions and it fixed it!  We'll file this under "Close enough" :)

Comment: So it was one of the following:  CodeAlike, Indent Guides, Productivity Power Tools, Scrum Powertools or Web Essentials.  I had ruled out all others by uninstalling them previously.

Comment: I also deleted Codalike..so it may have been that one like you said. I still have Web Essentials installed and I have never installed any of the other ones.

Comment: I'm reinstalling them one by one.  I just reinstalled Web Essentials and now VS keeps crashing.  Neat.

Comment: Well it's DEFINITELY codealike.  Can you update your answer?  Thanks for helping narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Often when things start misbehaving like this, I find one of three things has happened:
1) Somehow a modifier key gets stuck on.  Either my keyboard gets weird, or some software glitch happens.  Make sure none of your keys are stuck on unexpectedly.
2) Make sure accessibility services are off (or if you use some of them, make sure only the ones you use are on).  Some of these can really mess with you if you are not aware they are on.
3) Make sure your keyboard is in the expected region with the expected layout.  Sometimes this switches unexpectedly, and starts messing things up, and I won't realize for a long time.

Sorry if that isn't much help, but it is the only things I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned, `"I have disabled ALL extensions"`, so it should have nothing to do with any plugin.

Start by turn off IntelliSense

> Option－>Editor－>C/C++－>turn off IntelliSense with IntelliSense=FALSE

see if the whole auto complete feature is gone.

> "I disabled the one I installed most recently but it didn't help"

You have to make sure the extension is not running in the background. If any, kill them as long as it doesn't affect the VS.